# How To Change the field on focus in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Hello Sir I m making  an app in which i got stuck in a problem please help me out ...

in one page i m getting the data from server and displaying that data on the page now i m use Focusable for highlighting  them ...now my requirement is that when focus come on any data the it should change the field taking that name on which focus is present ..

following is the code which is showing the data on the page now it is working on field change where i need to click the label field ....

```
static LabelField[] CrDrLabels;

    public LowerCreditors() throws Exception {

        super(VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);

        CrDrLabels = new LabelField[CrDrList.VendorNameArr.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < CrDrLabels.length; i++) {
            final int t = i;

            VerticalFieldManager hfm = new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH) {

                protected void sublayout(int Width, int Height) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    super.sublayout(Width, Height);

                    setPositionChild(getField(0), 15, 0);

                    setPositionChild(getField(1), Display.getWidth()
                            - getFont().getAdvance(CrDrList.VendorValArr[t])
                            - 10, 0);
                }
            };

            CrDrLabels[i] = new LabelField(CrDrList.VendorNameArr[i],
                    LabelField.FOCUSABLE | Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH) {
                protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
                    fieldChanged(this, 0);
                    return true;
                };
            };

            LabelField Value = new LabelField(CrDrList.VendorValArr[i]);
            CrDrLabels[i].setPadding(0, 170, 0, 0);

            hfm.add(CrDrLabels[i]);
            hfm.add(Value);

            add(hfm);


        }
    }

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < CrDrList.VendorNameArr.length; i++) {
        getFieldWithFocus();
            if (field == CrDrLabels[i]) {

                String LN = CrDrLabels[i].getText();
                CrDrList.cname1 = LN;

                LabelField cname1 = CrDrLabels[i];
                CrDrList.selLad = CrDrLabels[i];

            }

        }
    }
```

and the the other code is

```
menu.add(new MenuItem("View last 5 days transaction", 20, 10) {
            public void run() {
                if(property.Status.equals("online"))
                {
                Viewlast5daystransaction();
                }

                else
                {
                    Dialog.alert("Please login Online to access the data..");
                }
            }

            String LedgerName = CrDrList.cname1;

            private void Viewlast5daystransaction() {
                //Dialog.alert("Last 5 Days Transaction");

                int resCode = 0;

                HttpConnection connection = null;
                try {
                    connection = getConn(property.LedgerDetailsURL);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    resCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                if(resCode==0)
                {
                    Dialog.alert("Internet Connectivity not available.. Please try again later..");

                    TallyA TA;

                    try {
                        TA = new TallyA();

                        UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen();
                        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(TA);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                sPostdata = "{\"tok\":\""
                        + CompanyList.tok;

                System.out.println("Postedddddd Dataaaaaaaaa" + sPostdata);
                try {
                    String response = LedgerSearchReport();

                    System.out.println("response" + response);

                    ParseBankdetails.parsebankdetails(response);

                    System.out.println("response : " + response);

                    if(response != null)
                    {
                    LastFiveDaysCr LF;
                    try {
                        LF = new LastFiveDaysCr();

                        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(LF);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Dialog.alert("No Data..");
                        Creditiors LF;
                        try {
                            LF = new Creditiors();

                            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(LF);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
```

in this field only i want that instead of field change there should be focus change ...
please help me on that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should implement the logic in  "**onFoucus()**"  method ,instead of using "**onfieldChanged()**" for CrDrLabels[i];

Comment: hello sir i tried a lot doing that but it is not happening i m not able to do that ..... i have made 2 different class for printing that particular page i want if on CrDrLabels[i] any focus will come then from the menu button i can perform any task ....like i can send the request to server ...please help me on that ...

Comment: have you tried to implement code for handling event on onfocus() method.?

Comment: yes sir i have tried for that also .... please help me and give some code on that ...